# Getting 'invalidQuery' exception in BigQuery while using INNER JOIN

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to `join` two StackOverflow tables for determining the average query response time. However I am a novice and am unable to `JOIN` the tables, please help.

---

```
Stackquery = """

    SELECT   
        ques.id,
        ques.accepted_answer_id,
        ques.creation_date,
        ques.last_activity_date,
        ansr.id, 
        ansr.accepted_answer_id, 
        ansr.creation_date, 
        ansr.last_activity_date
    FROM
        `bigquery-public-data:stackoverflow.posts_questions` as ques
        INNER JOIN
        'bigquery-public-data:stackoverflow.posts_answers' as ansr
        ON ques.accepted_answer_id = ansr.id
    WHERE
        MOD(ABS(FARM_FINGERPRINT(CAST(ques.last_activity_date AS STRING))),100000) = 1

"""

StackOverflowData = bq.Query(Stackquery).execute().result().to_dataframe()
```

> ExceptionTraceback (most recent call last)
>
> ```
> <ipython-input-72-80c29a281162> in <module>() 18 
>   """ 19 
> ---> 20 
>   StackOverflowData = bq.Query(Stackquery).execute().result().to_dataframe() ... 491 
> except KeyError: 492 
>     # The query was in error --> 493 
>     raise Exception(_utils.format_query_errors(query_result['status']['errors'])) 494 
>     return _query_job.QueryJob(job_id, table_name, self._sql, context=self._context) 495 
> Exception: invalidQuery: Encountered "" at line 14, column 3
> ```

Comment: I copy the comments **Traceback** to the Question. Please [edit] your Question to add relevant information to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the query itself; this works:

```
SELECT   
    ques.id,
    ques.accepted_answer_id,
    ques.last_activity_date,
    ansr.creation_date
FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` as ques
    INNER JOIN
    `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers` as ansr
    ON ques.accepted_answer_id = ansr.id
WHERE
    MOD(ABS(FARM_FINGERPRINT(CAST(ques.last_activity_date AS STRING))),100000) = 1
```

I recommend testing your queries in the [webUI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui) instead of running them in Python as its compiler will check the query and warn you of potential mistakes.